# subtracting last row from previous row and get total amount instead null in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am new to sql, Experts help required.
My current schema:

---

| USER | TRANS | CREDIT | DEBIT | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| U1111 | 1 | 2000 | 0 | 2000 |
| U1111 | 2 | 4000 | 0 | 6000 |
| U1111 | 3 | 0 | 1000 | 5000 |
| U1111 | 4 | 5000 | 0 | NULL |
| U2222 | 1 | 1000 | 0 | 1000 |
| U2222 | 2 | 0 | 500 | 500 |
| U2222 | 3 | 0 | 200 | NULL |

I want to subtract or add from previous row's total and get last row total calculated properly as show below
I am interested in last two row for each transaction.

Desired Output:

| USER | TRANS | CREDIT | DEBIT | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| U1111 | 1 | 2000 | 0 | 2000 |
| U1111 | 2 | 4000 | 0 | 6000 |
| U1111 | 3 | 0 | 500 | 5500 |
| U1111 | 4 | 5000 | 0 | 10500 |
| U2222 | 1 | 1000 | 0 | 1000 |
| U2222 | 2 | 0 | 500 | 500 |
| U2222 | 3 | 0 | 200 | 300 |

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUM( ~ ) OVER ( ~ )`

> ```
> SELECT
>   USER_,
>   TRANS,
>   CREDIT,
>   DEBIT,
>   sum(CREDIT-DEBIT) over (partition by USER_ order by TRANS) as running_total
> FROM table_name
> ORDER BY
>   USER_,
>   TRANS;
> ```
>
> ```
> USER_ | TRANS | CREDIT | DEBIT | RUNNING_TOTAL
> :---- | ----: | -----: | ----: | ------------:
> U1111 |     1 |   2000 |     0 |          2000
> U1111 |     2 |   4000 |     0 |          6000
> U1111 |     3 |      0 |   500 |          5500
> U1111 |     4 |   5000 |     0 |         10500
> U2222 |     1 |   1000 |     0 |          1000
> U2222 |     2 |      0 |   500 |           500
> U2222 |     3 |      0 |   200 |           300
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=73f03b23aebbc4cab0ca98ca7a471bf3)*

Answer (score 0):

You most probably shouldn't store `total` at all, but calculate it when you need it. Anyway, here's one option - `sum` function in its analytic form.

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * from test order by cuser, trans;

CU      TRANS     CREDIT      DEBIT      TOTAL
-- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
u1          1       2000          0          0
u1          2       4000          0          0
u1          3          0       1000          0
u1          4       5000          0          0
u2          1       1000          0          0
u2          2          0        500          0
u2          3          0        200          0

7 rows selected.
```

This is query that returns *running total*:

```
SQL> select cuser, trans, credit, debit,
  2    sum(credit - debit) over (partition by cuser order by trans) as total
  3  from test
  4  order by cuser, trans;

CU      TRANS     CREDIT      DEBIT      TOTAL
-- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
u1          1       2000          0       2000
u1          2       4000          0       6000
u1          3          0       1000       5000
u1          4       5000          0      10000
u2          1       1000          0       1000
u2          2          0        500        500
u2          3          0        200        300

7 rows selected.
```

To update the `total` column, use e.g. `merge`:

```
SQL> merge into test a
  2  using (select cuser, trans, credit, debit,
  3           sum(credit - debit) over (partition by cuser order by trans) as total
  4         from test
  5        ) b
  6  on (a.cuser = b.cuser and
  7      a.trans = b.trans
  8     )
  9  when matched then update set
 10    a.total = b.total;

7 rows merged.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from test order by cuser, trans;

CU      TRANS     CREDIT      DEBIT      TOTAL
-- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
u1          1       2000          0       2000
u1          2       4000          0       6000
u1          3          0       1000       5000
u1          4       5000          0      10000
u2          1       1000          0       1000
u2          2          0        500        500
u2          3          0        200        300

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```